# Writing unit tests for services in feathers without using a database

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I would like to write some unit tests for feathers services.

I want this test to run completely independent, which means i do not want to use the database.
This is an example snippet of my service which is using sequelize:


*src/services/messages/messages.service.js*

```js
// Initializes the `messages` service on path `/messages`
const createService = require('feathers-sequelize');
const createModel = require('../../models/messages.model');
const hooks = require('./messages.hooks');
const filters = require('./messages.filter');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const app = this;
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');
  const options = {
    name: 'messages',
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/messages', createService(options));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('messages');

  service.hooks(hooks);

  if (service.filter) {
    service.filter(filters);
  }
};
```

I would maybe try to mock the database with the library [sequelize-test-helpers](https://github.com/davesag/sequelize-test-helpers) but I am not sure how this would work in combination with feathers. 


This is how my current test in typescript for this service looks like:


*src/test/services/messages.test.ts*

```js
import assert from 'assert';
import { app } from '../../src/app';

describe('\'messages\' service', () => {

  before(() => {
  // maybe add an entry to the mocked database
  });

  after(() => {
  // maybe delete that entry
  });

  it('registered the service', () => {
    const service = app.service('messages');

    assert.ok(service, 'Registered the service');
  });

  it('returns a single record', async () => {
    // get result with id 1 (maybe added item in before-hook)
    const res = await service.get(1);
    should().exist(res);
    res.should.be.a('object');
    // more checks...
  });
});
```

The first '**it(...)**' was generated by feathers itself and the second '**it(...)**' shows the functionality I want the test to have.

But the problem is that I am not sure how to write this test so that the service will not use the original database.

Does anybody of you have an idea how I could write a test for a feathers service without using the actual database?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is a unit test that essentially just is testing feathers-sequelize useful?  Unless you're trying to test additional functionality on top of feathers-sequelize, I guess I don't see the utility in writing tests that just validatate that a 3rd party library does what it says it does.

Comment: well, I want to test every bit of my application even the services. I could also do some integration tests but this would be a little bit to overkill for a single service in my opinion

Comment: Have you looked at the tests for the feathers adapater you are using? Normally they already have good coverage of unit tests. If you are not extending your service there is probably no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @floriannorbertbepunkt The problem with the [adapter tests](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/blob/master/packages/adapter-tests/lib/methods.js) is that they are using newly generated services: `const app = feathers()
    .use('/people', memory({ events }))` . I would like to test my own services like: `app.service('messages')` without newly generating it.

Answer (score 0):

Set environment to TEST and in config set the database on the test.json . As seen here : https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/testing.html#test-database-setup

Comment: Do no hestitate to add some useful quote extracted from the link. This way you post will still be valid even if the link dies!